# (VF) How Do I pull a picklist from a related object as an input field onto a VF page that uses the Standard Controller with extensions?

Tags: visualforce, picklist, controller-extension, cross-object

> **Scenario:** I've created a VF page that uses the Account standard controller with an extension that I created to pull contacts related
>   to that account into a multi-selectable list using a wrapper class.
>   Guests that access this page with the correct account ?id= in the URL
>   are able to select multiple existing contacts at a time and, using 2
>   command buttons, perform a DML update on the selected records to set a
>   Boolean to True or False. This works fine.

---

> **Objective:** I would like to extend it so that guests that access the page can also add new contacts to the list from the same page,
>   using a separate pageblock and set of command buttons.

---

I figured I would accomplish this by just making a few public {get; set;} Strings in the extension and adding inputFields to the page that set those public Strings and then make a custom save command that puts together a new contact record related to the account with the values of the strings and does a DML and then a PageReference to reload the page.

This is fine I'm sure for First Name, Last Name, and Email... but we also have a custom Picklist on the Contact object called Title__c. I've never rendered a picklist in VF before, and especially not a picklist from the account's child object through custom extension.

> **Question:** How do I render the Contact picklist, with the correct values, on the custom Account VF page and then get the value that was
>   selected to insert into the new record before DML, so that I can have
>   a 'create new' style form on the page that allows them to dump in new
>   contacts on the fly?
>
> **Alternative Question:** Can I, alternatively, somehow create my own custom picklist with my own custom values via the extension class
>   itself, and then get the option that they selected and pass it using
>   set; to a string in the extension?

I hope this makes sense, happy to clarify or provide existing extension/page code if deemed necessary.

Comment: how do you cast the value into the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller:

```
    public List<SelectOption> myPicklist { get;private set; }

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult statusFieldDescription = Contact.FIELD_API_NAME.getDescribe();
    myPicklist = new list<SelectOption>();
    //this line is optional if you want kind of default or empty value
    //myPicklist.add(new SelectOption('--None--','--None--'));
    for (Schema.Picklistentry picklistEntry : statusFieldDescription.getPicklistValues())
    {
        myPicklist.add(new SelectOption(pickListEntry.getValue(),pickListEntry.getLabel()));
    }
```

VisualForce Page:

```
<apex:selectList size="1" value="{!VARIABLE_TO_STORE}">
<apex:selectOptions value="{!myPicklist}"/> 
</apex:selectList>
```

you can add action support onchange to Visualforce if you want to store variable at time it changes.

Comment: Controller code wasn't perfect, but provided the detail I needed for understanding how to gather picklist values from an existing Salesforce field AND included my alternative question of how to build your own values into a custom controller based picklist. Working great now. +1, Thank you!

Comment: can you share some of the syntax changes you needed to make? thanks!

Comment: how do you cast the value into the object?